# Problem with JQuery Cycle Plugin, Webkit Browsers and images

Tags: jquery, image, webkit, cycle

I am trying to create an animated banner using JQuery, rather than use an animated gif.
The Cycle Plugin executes this well in FireFox, but in Safari and Chrome, upon initially loading the page, I do not observe the "slideshow" and only see a single image.  I have attempted to resolve this via .load(), preloading the images, and using display: hidden on the subsequent images, each without success.  Curiously, I have noticed that the single image that does load is in fact the smallest image (in file size) of all the images.

Any input is appreciated.  I am stumped.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('#banner').cycle({
         fx: 'none',
     delay: 0,
     speed: 500,
     autostop: true,
         autostopCount: 8,
timeoutFn: function(currElement, nextElement, opts, isForward) {
          opts.myTimeoutCount = (opts.myTimeoutCount + 1) % opts.myTimeouts.length;
          return opts.myTimeouts[opts.myTimeoutCount];
    },
    myTimeouts: [1000,1000,500,500,500,2000,2000,1000],
    myTimeoutCount: 0
    });
});


<div id="banner">
    <img src="images/if_300x250_banner_1.gif" width="300" height="250" />
    <img src="images/if_300x250_banner_2.gif" width="300" height="250" />
    <img src="images/if_300x250_banner_3.gif" width="300" height="250" />
    <img src="images/if_300x250_banner_4.gif" width="300" height="250" />
    <img src="images/if_300x250_banner_5.gif" width="300" height="250" />
    <img src="images/if_300x250_banner_6.gif" width="300" height="250" />
    <img src="images/if_300x250_banner_7.gif" width="300" height="250" />
    <img src="images/if_300x250_banner_8.gif" width="300" height="250" />
```

Comment: Are you just wanting to loop through each image, replacing the current image with the proceeding one?

Comment: Yes Rob, exactly what I am trying to do.  However I do need to be able to control the time that each image is displayed, hence the TimeoutFN function.

Answer (score 1):

Persistence pays off.  It turned out that the problem was not with JQuery, the Cycle Plugin, or the Webkit browsers, but with the images.  The source PSD that I used to create the gifs held the Photoshop layers in an animation timeline and that data was being included when I was using "Save for Web & Devices" in Photoshop- interesting that it did not pose a problem in Firefox.  The solution was to simply "Delete Animation" in the Animation palette and save the gifs once more.

Thanks to all who pondered this one.